# MySQL Lock Wait Timeout using Model Factories

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a very small dataset being generated in a method on a Test Class, I had tried having the data generated in the `setUp()` method but it was leading to a lock wait timeout for every test.  Moving this code out of the `setUp()` method and putting it in it's own method has helped a bit.  Meaning that not every test complains about the locks.

I am using the DatabaseTransactions trait that is in Laravel 5.2 so that the database is reset before each test case is run.

In every test case that I have I make a call to get the mock data like this.

```
$data = self::getRandomCommunityWithAssociatedData();
```

The actual method only generates a few community objects and user objects for the created community.

```
public static function getRandomCommunityWithAssociatedData()
{
    self::$communities = factory(\Community::class, self::COMMUNITIES_TO_CREATE)->create()->each(function ($community) {
        self::$users[$community->id] = factory(User::class, self::USERS_TO_CREATE)->create()->each(function (\User $user) use ($community) {
            $user->community()->associate($community);
        });

        self::$admins[$community->id] = factory(User::class, 'superadmin', self::ADMINS_TO_CREATE)->create()->each(function (\User $admin) use ($community) {
            $admin->community()->associate($community);
        });
    });

    $community = self::$communities[mt_rand(0, count(self::$communities) - 1)];

    return ['community' => $community, 'users' => self::$users[$community->id], 'admins' => self::$admins[$community->id]];
}
```

There are a few constants in use in that method and they are used to determine how many of each object to create.  Currently I am creating 2 communities and 3 users and 2 admins for each community instance.

The lock wait timeouts are not predictable, one run it could happen on the first test case, another run it could happen on the 5th test case.

I have tried to increase the time in which MySQL waits for the lock to 500 seconds and I am still getting the timeouts.  Increasing this time really is not an option because the tests need to be able to run on all environments.

Any thoughts as to why I might be getting these lock wait timeouts when using the DatabaseTransactions trait in Laravel 5.2 with such a small dataset?

```
1) UserEmailNotificationsTest::testActiveAdminReceivesNewCommentEmailNotification
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction (SQL: insert into `communities` (`
```

The above query that is executed is a simple insert on the community table and there are no complicated subqueries or anything like that going on in this data generation.

Enabled the query log, results.

```
       30 Query START TRANSACTION
       30 Query SAVEPOINT trans2
       30 Prepare   insert into `communities` (`viddler_id`, `domain`, `subdomain`, `active`, `max_seats`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `assignment_seats`, `general_settings`, `access_settings`, `branding_settings`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
       30 Execute   insert into `communities` (`viddler_id`, `domain`, `subdomain`, `active`, `max_seats`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `assignment_seats`, `general_settings`, `access_settings`, `branding_settings`) values ('74', 'gaylord.com', 'qui', '1', '24', '2016-03-30 16:25:45', '2016-04-04 02:27:04', '23', 'a:11:{s:5:\"title\";s:0:\"\";s:11:\"description\";s:0:\"\";s:10:\"meta_title\";s:0:\"\";s:16:\"meta_description\";s:0:\"\";s:13:\"meta_keywords\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"thumbnail_display\";s:0:\"\";s:18:\"group_nomenclature\";s:8:\"Channels\";s:13:\"home_template\";s:0:\"\";s:11:\"api_version\";s:1:\"2\";s:8:\"language\";s:2:\"en\";s:21:\"use_nested_navigation\";i:0;}', 'a:10:{s:12:\"restrictions\";s:10:\"Restricted\";s:17:\"auto_registration\";i:0;s:14:\"default_active\";i:0;s:12:\"oauth_google\";i:0;s:14:\"oauth_facebook\";i:0;s:14:\"oauth_linkedin\";i:0;s:16:\"oauth_reg_google\";i:0;s:18:\"oauth_reg_facebook\";i:0;s:18:\"oauth_reg_linkedin\";i:0;s:11:\"lti_enabled\";i:0;}', 'a:14:{s:13:\"contact_email\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"contact_link_text\";s:0:\"\";s:9:\"logo_file\";s:0:\"\";s:14:\"carousel_items\";s:0:\"\";s:11:\"html_header\";s:0:\"\";s:16:\"footer_copyright\";s:45:\"&copy; 2015 Viddler Inc. All Rights Reserved.\";s:19:\"footer_privacy_link\";s:37:\"http://www.viddler.com/privacy-policy\";s:17:\"footer_terms_link\";s:35:\"http://www.viddler.com/terms-of-use\";s:14:\"help_link_text\";s:4:\"Help\";s:9:\"help_link\";s:0:\"\";s:7:\"color_1\";s:7:\"#ffffff\";s:7:\"color_2\";s:7:\"#2C333C\";s:7:\"color_3\";s:7:\"#2C333C\";s:7:\"color_4\";s:7:\"#60a1d7\";}')
160404  9:30:25    30 Close stmt
       21 Query ROLLBACK
       21 Quit
       22 Query ROLLBACK
       22 Quit
       23 Query ROLLBACK
       23 Quit
       24 Query ROLLBACK
       24 Quit
       25 Query ROLLBACK
       25 Quit
       26 Query ROLLBACK
       26 Quit
       27 Query ROLLBACK
       27 Quit
       28 Query ROLLBACK
       28 Quit
       29 Query ROLLBACK
       29 Quit
       30 Query ROLLBACK
       30 Quit
```

Comment: enable the query log and look which queries cause the deadlock. And you should set the timeout back to a normal level.

Comment: It is the insert into the communities table that is failing.  I have updated the question above to show the data from the mysql query log.

Comment: While not answering your question, i suggest moving to sqlite for testing only. It will dramatically speed up the run time of your tests.

Comment: I thought that is generally caused by multiple queries running against the same table. Can you end the transaction with every call? What happens if you're logged into the DB and call `show open tables where in_use>0;` while the tests are running? What happens if you terminate the testing process?

Comment: +1 for @Mysteryos comment on sqlite. You can setup your phpunit to use sqlite for testing and store in memory, drastically increasing performance. Have a look at https://vimeo.com/151390908

Comment: Try to using persistent connection to mysql.

Answer (score 2):

So, increasing the lock wait timeout is not a best practice; [the best practice is to catch the error and recover](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-error-handling.html).

Officially, this is what you should be doing:

> Both deadlocks and lock wait timeouts are normal on busy servers and
>   it is necessary **for applications to be aware that they may happen and
>   handle them by retrying.** You can make them less likely by **doing as
>   little work as possible between the first change to data during a
>   transaction and the commit**, so the locks are held for the shortest
>   possible time and for the smallest possible number of rows. **Sometimes
>   splitting work between different transactions may be practical and
>   helpful.**